# How to replace the Div tag with another div tag on same place without redirecting to other page using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on JSP project using Bootstrap for front end.

I have a query about html design. **How to replace the Div tag with another div tag on same place without redirecting to other page using bootstrap..?**

Consider gmail as an example. It replaces the mails list div with the e-mail data div when you click a particular mail..

Please give me a solution.

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: try ajax load method and load the contents to the same div!

Comment: what we can called to that concept in ajax.? Does anyone have Demo.? Because i am unknown about AJAX..

Comment: @tejas i posted an answer with how to easily implement your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you have jQuery since you use Bootstrap. You have to use an Ajax call, and load the content of the call inside your div:

```
$.get( "yourpage.html", function( data ) {
   $( "#result" ).html( data );
});
```

Where 'result' is the id of your div

You probably want to wrap this inside an onClick event.